# Azure AD Synchronization using SCIM and Asp.Net Web-Services

Tags: c#, azure, active-directory, azure-active-directory, scim

I want to Sync users on an Azure AD with my DB and keep it up-to-date.
I found this article that is using SCIM and C# which it is exactly what I'm looking for, but I can't understand some steps, and I made a research for an alternative ways to do it, but most of the results were referring to the same article:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/active-directory-scim-provisioning
I tried to download the code referenced in the article, here https://github.com/Azure/AzureAD-BYOA-Provisioning-Samples/tree/master
and I ran it with no errors,
and I followed the steps but I reached to a dead end.
My Questions are:

- is there any alternatives or this is the only way to do it?
- in the article, "To create a sample SCIM endpoint" step 7, I didn't understand why it should run like this "FileAgnt.exe http://ip-address:9000 TargetFile.csv"
- What is the "SCIM endpoint " mentioned in section "To register the sample SCIM endpoint in Azure AD" and also steps from 6 to 11 it didn't work with me.

I would really appreciate if I can have a different reference or another tutorial or a 1 2 3 steps to follow.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

> in the article, "To create a sample SCIM endpoint" step 7, I didn't understand why it should run like this "FileAgnt.exe http://ip-address:9000 TargetFile.csv"

I checked the tutorial you provided, the instruction does not match the relevant github sample. For the **FileProvisioningAgent** project, if we run the `FileAgnt.exe`, we may retrieve the following result:

[image]

Per my testing, you need to build the **FileProvisioningService** project and execute it on your Windows machine to listen at the address your specified, and output all assigned and provisioned users and groups into the CSV file.

```
FileSvc.exe http://<ip-address>:9000 TargetFile.csv
```

> What is the "SCIM endpoint " mentioned in section "To register the sample SCIM endpoint in Azure AD" and also steps from 6 to 11 it didn't work with me.

Per my understanding, Azure AD would try to access the endpoint exposed by your Windows machine. And your Windows machine would listen the endpoint and receive the provisioned users from Azure AD. I have no condition to do this configuration, but you could check your SCIM endpoint could be accessed via the internet and the related port is not blocked by Windows Firewall.

> is there any alternatives or this is the only way to do it?

As [Automate provisioning to SCIM-enabled apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/active-directory-scim-provisioning#overview) mentioned as follows:

> The initial sync takes longer to perform than subsequent syncs, which occur approximately every 20 minutes as long as the service is running.

Per my understanding, you may try to build your application and use [Azure AD Graph](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ad/graph/api/api-catalog) or [Microsoft Graph](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/overview) to retrieve the users and groups, then insert / update into your DB.

Comment: Thanks, what about http://localhost:9000 was it supposed to be the link specified in the Provisioning section in the AD Portal?

Comment: The SCIM endpoint (`http://<ip-address>:9000`) is exposed by your Windows machine, and you need to register your SCIM endpoint in Azure AD. Moreover, your could listen any other port instead of 9000. As the tutorial states that once connected, Azure AD runs a synchronization process every 20 minutes where it queries the application's SCIM endpoint for assigned users and groups, and creates or modifies them according to the assignment details.